# How to query data from GitHub Discussions using GitHub's GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, github-api

I want to query the data from [`https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions`](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions) via GitHub's GraphQL API but I don't know how to access it.

GitHub Discussions are a beta feature that's currently available only on a few repos, [`prisma/prisma`](https://github.com/prisma/prisma) being one of them. I would have expected that I can query the data in a similar fashion to querying *issues* and *pull requests* of a repo:

```
{
  repository(
    owner: "prisma"
    name: "prisma"
  ) {
    pullRequests(first: 5 orderBy: {
      field: CREATED_AT,
      direction: DESC
    }) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
        }
      }
    }
    issues(first: 5 orderBy: {
      field: CREATED_AT,
      direction: DESC
    }) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm basically looking for a query that would allow me to do this:

```
{
  repository(
    owner: "prisma"
    name: "prisma"
  ) {
    # this doesn't work
    discussions(first: 5 orderBy: {
      field: CREATED_AT,
      direction: DESC
    }) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But such a `discussions` property doesn't exist on the `Repository` type in the GitHub API.

**EDIT (Dec 8, 2020)**: I learned from the GitHub team that the data is not yet available via the public GraphQL API but they're working on releasing it soon. I'll leave the question open until it's available.